# Using prompt and if and spring to number together in javascript

Tags: javascript

What I want to do is that if I type some text like `Hello!` in prompt I'll activate the first condition and if I write `5` in prompt I activate the second condition and anything else I activate the last condition. But It's not happening and I can't figure it out.

```js
let fx = +prompt('?', '');
if (fx == null) {
  alert('f');
} else if (fx == 5) {
  alert('s');
} else {
  alert('gfgfg');
}
```

Comment: This is working for me.  If I type the number 5, I am `alert`ed "s".  What exactly isn't working.  What steps have you taken to debug?

Comment: my purpose is if I type a text ( "Hello" for example), I get alerted "f" which I'm not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check for [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) with [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) and display a text which reflects the input.

If you prompt a value which is not convertable to a number by using an [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus), you get `NaN` as value. For checking this value you need to use the above mentioned function which returns a boolean value.

```js
let fx = +prompt('?', '');

if (isNaN(fx)) {
    console.log('not a number');
} else if (fx === 5) {
    console.log('five!');
} else {
    console.log('some other number not 5');
}
```